# Passing a FORTRAN object to C and vice versa

Tags: c, object, fortran, argument-passing, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have my Fortran object i.e.

```
this%object%a

this%object%b

this%object%c
```

I want to pass it to a code written in C, I am predominately a FORTRAN programmer and I have had very little exposure to C. I am using `iso_c_binding` to pass integers and arrays but now I need to pass objects.

I define the object in the following way

```
    TYPE object

         INTEGER                                  :: a

         INTEGER                                  :: b

         INTEGER                                  :: c

    END TYPE object
```

Comment: How is your Fortran object declared? Also, your question is tagged fortran90 but IIRC ISO_C_BINDING is a Fortran 2003 feature, (currently supported by Intel Fortran among others)

Comment: Do you know C structs? How do your Fortran types look like? Some can be interoperable, some cannot. @deStrangis retagged.

Comment: what FORTRAN type do I need? @deStrangis

Comment: Vladimir just answered your question. I'm upvoting the question and the answer, I believe they're very useful as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make interoperable types:

```
use iso_c_binding

TYPE, BIND(C) :: object

     INTEGER(c_int)                                :: a

     INTEGER(c_int)                                :: b

     INTEGER(c_int)                                :: c

END TYPE object

type(object) :: o
```

There are restrictions in the standard on the object. For example, it cannot contain allocatable or pointer components.

When you pass it to an interoperable procedure:

```
void sub(c_object* x){}

subroutine sub(x) bind(C,name="sub")
  type(object), intent(inout) :: x
end subroutine

call sub(o)
```

it is interoperable with a C struct

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} c_object;
```

You can also pass non-interoperable types to C, but you have to use pointers:

```
subroutine sub2(x) bind(C,name="sub")
  type(c_ptr), value :: x
end subroutine

call sub2(loc(o))
```