# Padding at the end of an array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fortran, padding

I asked the following question on FORTRAN/C linking [Passing a FORTRAN object to C and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606958/passing-a-fortran-object-to-c-and-vice-versa) and have another question which is to do with C.

Can someone explain the reason for padding of an array at the end of a struct? I get my object from FORTRAN in C and define struct and substructs:

```
struct ginfo {
  int printproc;  
  double *x;
};

struct sinfo {
  double a,b,c,d,e;
  int max_steps;
};

struct cons {
  struct ginfo  pointer1; 
  struct sinfo pointer2; 
};

extern void printc_(struct cons *v)
{
    double *t1;
    int u,w;

    u = v -> pointer1.printproc;
    t1 = v -> pointer1.x;
    w = v -> pointer2.max_steps;
}
```

This is my C code. For me to access "max_steps" after "x", it requires me to put the dummy variables a,b,c,d,e (to get past the padding I am GUESSING).

Fortran code

```
TYPE Storage
     INTEGER :: printproc
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:)  , ALLOCATABLE     :: x
END TYPE Storage


TYPE Storage1
     INTEGER :: max_steps
END TYPE Storage1

TYPE example
    TYPE(Storage)   :: JAC
    TYPE(Storage1)   :: MAT
END TYPE example

  TYPE(example)                          :: cons

ALLOCATE(cons%JAC%x(1:10))

cons%JAC%x(:) = 1.23

 call printc( cons )
```

I am asking why I need the padding? And why it is always constant no matter the size of "x"?

FYI: I do not code with C

Comment: 2. because `x` is a pointer and not an array, so you didn't change it's size.

Comment: I have defined x as an array in FORTRAN and then passed it to via in an object

Comment: More code will be necessary to say anything about your Fortran/C interoperability you do.

Comment: 2. X is not an array, it's a pointer. It's size is always constant. Size of array it's pointing to is completely different thing. 1. Correct way: `struct a { : 320; int max_steps;};` 320 means number of bits. It can be also written as `: sizeof(double)*5*8;`

Comment: @Matty your code formatting for the fortran code posted could use looking at. I'd do it myself, but I'd need to wait for moderation.

Comment: This is not enough, how do you pass it from Fortran? And please fix the formatting.

Comment: And please don't EVER use `SEQUENCE` when interfacing with C. That CAN'T work. In the very answer you linked I have shown you how to use `bind(C)` instead. BTW it is *Fortran*, not FORTRAN for almost 25 years.

Comment: Ok, I decided to use a method without bind(C)

Comment: My code works fine, I just wanted to understand padding better

Comment: Does  it? How do you access the `ALLOCATABLE` array in C? You are playing with matches in a haystack if you do not understand the internal representation of array descriptors and padding right.

Comment: double t2;  t2 = v1 -> pointer1.x;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  We still can't see exactly what you are trying to do / how you are doing it.  Where is printc defined? how is it defined? what is wrong with it?

Comment: I have added some text which will hopefully make my question clearer

Comment: Show concrete simple example of how you do the padding. Clearly indicate the Fortran and C equivalents of the type/struct and where did you put the padding, otherwise we can't say anything. Don't hesitate to clear most of your question, don't just append more and more edits. Make it simple.

Comment: I have rewritten the question, please see update

Comment: Now there is no `sequence`, should it be there, or not?

Comment: I took heed of your above comment... It seems not to effect the result I mention above anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If it was only the struct padding, it could be quite random. Fortran is allowed to position the components as it wants, but C is required to not change the order of the members. That's why you should use `bind(C)` which enforces the C behavior.
2. When you use `SEQUENCE` you have zero padding. The problem is it is difficult to force this in C.
3. The main reason. The `ALLOCATABLE` array is NOT at all the same as the C pointer. It is quite difficult descriptor which has many fields (sizes in all dimensions, first index in all dimensions, ...) and it can differ among compilers. So your padding is in fact just masking the parts of the descriptor, until you luckily find the real pointer to the data. You are lucky, that `allocatable` arrays are required to be contiguous, so in the end it may work.
4. Why it is independent of the size? Because it is a pointer. The actual data are somewhere else. Both in C and in Fortran. In Fortran there are other parts of the descriptor in addition to the address, but still it is just a sort of a pointer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I will implement the bind(C) if it becomes more problematic

Comment: Although in the answer to my previous question you stated that bind(C) can't be used with allocatable variables?

Comment: @Matty Yes, they cannot, because in C you would have to guess, as you do, where is the actual pointer. That's why in proper modern C interop you should have `type(c_ptr)` in the struct. It may be just a proxy type for an actual Fortran type which has the allocatable array.